# Best way to handle decoupling in Go with similar structs in two different packages but subitem in struct making it difficult?

Tags: go, dependencies

I'm relatively new to go and have been doing a massive rewrite trying to reduce my dependency graph as much as possible. I'm pretty happy with where I got it but there is this one part I am not sure how to best handle. If the answer is, "You are going to have that dependency between the two", that's fine too, I'm just looking for a good approach, not expecting miracles.

So below I have two packages, `a` & `b`, and they both have identical structs. Normally you could convert one to the other in main but each has a subitem which is also a struct and that's stopping Go from allowing it even though the subitems have identical signatures.

One way would be to just reference A.TzConfig in the struct in B and let there be a dependency but that's what I am trying to get rid of.

I guess another way is to create an interface and then get the values of Loc through methods, I think that would work but I haven't tried it yet as that means creating methods for something that's just a structure of data (the actual structure has a lot of items, I reduced it to the essentials for simplicity here) which seems like overkill.

I could move TzConfig into a third module so they would both reference that instead of one referencing the other and that's about all I have thought of.

So my question is, from someone with a real experience, what would be the best way to deal with this scenario in go?

I should mention that the reason they have duplicated structs was just because I was trying to break the dependency between them, the original code just had the struct in one package and the other package referencing it.

```
package a

type Cfg struct {
    Addr                 string
    Loc                  TzConfig
}

type TzConfig struct {
    String string
    TZ     *time.Location `validate:"noDescent"`
}

func GetCfg() Cfg {
    t, _ := time.LoadLocation(`MST`)
    return Cfg{
        Addr: "abc",
        Host: "a.bc.d",
        Loc:  config.TzConfig{
            String: "MST",
            TZ:     t,
        },
    }
}
```

```
package b

type Cfg struct {
    Addr                 string
    Loc                  TzConfig
}

type TzConfig struct {
    String string
    TZ     *time.Location `validate:"noDescent"`
}

func DoSomethingWithConfig(c Cfg) {
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

```
package main

main() {
     c := a.GetCfg()
     d := b.DoSomethingWithConfig(b.Cg(c))
     fmt.Println(d)
}
```

Comment: The answer may be subjective. Based on the info given here I would create a third package and put the common objects there. There are cases where other options also make sense

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I have been leaning.

Comment: My main contending thought is that I have cleaned it up so much and the dependencies look good enough so that I could just leave this one as a dependency. My one new thought is that I just learned that go has generics now but generics seems like a solution to a different problem so I haven't dived into that as a possible solution.

Comment: You do not need generics here. If both structs are identical you should move the top level struct to a common pkg as well. If necessary you can embed that common struct to pkg specific configs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the suggestion provided by @BurakSerdar are completely fine and fits very well for your scenario. I've rewritten the code in this way.

#### `package common`

```golang
package common

import "time"

type Cfg struct {
    Addr string
    Loc  TzConfig
}

type TzConfig struct {
    String string
    TZ     *time.Location `validate:"noDescent"`
}
```

Here, you should put the common structs, functions, methods, and so on.

#### `package a`

```golang
package a

import (
    "dependencies/common"
    "time"
)

type Cfg struct {
    common.Cfg
    Host string
}

func GetCfg() Cfg {
    t, _ := time.LoadLocation(`MST`)
    return Cfg{
        Cfg: common.Cfg{
            Addr: "abc",
            Loc: common.TzConfig{
                String: "MST",
                TZ:     t,
            },
        },
        Host: "a.bc.d",
    }
}
```

Here, you have the specific code related to the package `a` that inherits the shared code from the `common` package, as you can see in the `import` section.

> Please note that I used the structs embedding feature to get the shared fields defined within the `common` package.

#### `package b`

```golang
package b

import (
    "dependencies/common"
    "fmt"
)

func DoSomethingWithConfig(c common.Cfg) string {
    return fmt.Sprint(c)
}
```

Here, there is nothing special to mention.

#### `package main`

```golang
package main

import (
    "dependencies/a"
    "dependencies/b"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c := a.GetCfg()
    d := b.DoSomethingWithConfig(c.Cfg)
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

Here, the code should be pretty straightforward. I imported packages `a` and `b` to exploit their functionalities.

Again, I'd like to be clear that this is a subjective topic, hence there isn't a silver bullet solution. To me, looks neat and clear. I would have chosen this way for sure. Let me know and thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I was always leaning towards that and I would have liked that [Burak Serdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11923999/burak-serdar) did what you did and put an answer so that I could credit him with it but since you did create an answer, I'm marking yours as the answer.